# Working with types in typescript

Tags: arrays

I would like to declare an object that has the following structure

```
public car = {
    price: 20000,
    currency: EUR,
    seller: null,
    model: {
        color: null,
        type: null,
        year: null
    } as Array<object>
};
```

Then, when I work with this object, I have something like

```
public addProduct(typeId: number): void {
    this.car.model.push({type: typeId});
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I defined the `model` object, as using `as Array<object>` generates something alone the lines

```
Type '{ color: null; type: null; year: null; }' cannot be converted to type 'object[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type '{ color: null; type: null; year: null; }
```

I couldn't find a proper why to define this. It was important to use `push` to generate an "empty" object to which I can add the attributes from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object in typescript like

```
let car: any = {
  price: 20000,
  currency: 'EUR',
  seller: null,
  model: [
    { color: 'red', type: 'one', year: '2000' }, 
    { color: 'blue', type: 'two', year: '2001' }
  ]
}
```

Then you can do what you wanted

```
car.model.push({ color: 'green', type: 'three', year: '2002' });
```

to add a new model, or to fetch one

```
car.model[0] // returns { color: 'red', type: 'one', year: '2000' }
```

Another alternative would be to create a class instead of an object

```
export class Car {
  public price: number;
  public currency: string;
  public seller: string;
  public models: any[];

  constructor() { }
}
```

And then put all the appropriate methods inside the class.

Comment: In your first case, why can't I do a `push` with just one of the values, the rest being set to `null` or whatever the defaults are. As in `car.model.push({ year: '2002' });` ?

Comment: no1 said you can't, simply make `model: []` if you want an empty array and push in it later on, I've just put something inside for the example or 
if you want empty values you can initialize it with all null values doesn't matter
`model: [ { color: null, type: null, year: null }] ` also works but I don't see why would you want null values if you can make it an empty array